# Discrete Fourier transform of signal product equals to periodic convolution of signal DFTs?

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution, signal-processing, fourier-transform

I am referring to this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Circular_convolution_theorem_and_cross-correlation_theorem

I generated a simple case where $y=sinc(x_N), Y=DFT(y)$, $x_N$ is a discrete signal of length $N$. I am trying to validate if $DFT(y^2)=Y*Y$, where $*$ denotes periodic convolution. But I guess there should be some normalization w.r.t signal length as well. I wrote a Matlab script:

```
x = linspace(1,100,1000);
y = sinc(x);
fy = fft(y);    %DFT of original y
cfy2 = cconv(fy, fy);   % circular convolution of DFT(y) with itself

y2 = y.^2;  
fy2 = fft(y2);  % directly compute DFT of y^2

figure
hold on;
plot(abs(cfy2(1:length(fy2)))/length(y)) % normalized by length of signal
plot(abs(fy2));
```

The result is that they do not match. [See curves here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzV1K.png). This property should hold theoretically. But can someone tell me where did I do wrong?

Comment: Check the help for cconv: C = cconv(A, B, N) circularly convolves vectors A and B.  The resulting vector is length N. **If omitted, N defaults to LENGTH(A)+LENGTH(B)-1. When N = LENGTH(A)+LENGTH(B)-1, the circular convolution is equivalent to the linear convolution computed by CONV.**

Comment: Define `q` to be any vector you want. The following will always be zero: `max( abs( cconv(q,q,length(q)) - ifft( fft(q) .* fft(q) ) ) )`

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 You are right. It's because I did not use cconv properly.